# Native method to skip Nans in a lambda function?

Tags: pandas, nan

I was wondering if there's a native method to skip nans in a lambda function. 
I have dataframe 'y' in the form below. I'm attempting to turn the Year column into ints. But the lambda function breaks because of the NaN. I've come up with the below, but I'm wondering if there are better ways to deal with this pervasive issue? Thanks!

```
       Year
137    2005
138     NaN
```

To deal with it, i just used try/except. I wonder if there' a better way to deal with NaNs.

```
def turn_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return np.nan

y.Year.apply(lambda x: turn_int(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` doesn't have a representation of NaN. The normal way to deal with it would be to drop all the NaN's first:

```
year = y.Year.dropna().astype(int)
```

Comment: the one reason i'm hesitating doing this is that the indices won't match up. i wanted to be able to use the old dataframe

Comment: The indices will still align when you do operations on both, I'm not sure what you mean? Perhaps you shoud use `np.trunc(y.Year)`, and leave the datatype as float, if you really want to be able to see missing data.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for int series.

```
import numpy as np
y['year'] = y['year'].apply(lambda x:x if np.isnan(x) else int(x))
```